# How to set the transimission line impedance of Type-C to DisplayPort?

Tags: pcb, impedance, layout, usb-c, displayport

I have drawn a PCB adapter board to convert the Type-C signal to DisplayPort, using the CYPD3120 scheme from Infineon. The schematic is as follows:
[image]
(A clearer version can be found here [Schematic.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/fytbdwbben5imxsz3m9u7/SCH_USBC2DP_1.0.0_2023-07-29.pdf?rlkey=gao1mowwrmsbtovp5mc14742x&dl=0))
The signals of TX1, TX2, RX1, and RX2 from Type-C are converted to the 4-lane signals of DisplayPort.

The adapter board can now transform the Type-C signal from Surface Pro 7 to drive a 2K screen, 2556 * 1440, 60 Hz. But when driving the 4K screen, there is a strip of noise, like:
[image]

I think it's my layout problem for the impedance. I have several questions:

1. Should the reference plane under the pins of the Type-C and DisplayPort connector be empty to keep impedance continuity?
2. The recommended impedance for the lines from the USB specification is 90 ohm, while 100 ohm from the DisplayPort specification. Then what is the impedance value of the line on the adapter board? The line connects directly from the Type-C connector to the DisplayPort connector or through a data switch chip on the board.
3. Length matching. I used a Type-C receptacle on the board (USB1 in the schematic). According to the specification of DisplayPort over Type-C, I put AC coupling capacitors on the TX routes. No capacitors on the RX routes. Then how should the length match between TX and RX routes from Type-C to data switch chip VL171? Should the sum of the TX line length before and after the capacitor be equal to the length of the RX line?
4. I use a four-layer board with a stack of signal-GND-PWR-signal. Then when the differential pair changes layers from the top to the bottom, no current return vias connecting different GND layers can be placed around the layer-changing vias as can be done in a six-layer stack. Any good way to provide a current return path for the differential pair?

*To my understanding, the differential pair should have a reference plane to form the transmission line. The reference plane works as a return path for the electromagnetic wave, no matter whether the wave is flowing downstream or upstream. The lines on the top layer use the GND plane as a reference while the lines on the bottom layer use the PWR plane as a reference. When the lines change layers from the top to the bottom, their reference also changes from the GND to the PWR plane. Then the return path of the electromagnetic wave is broken since the GND plane can not be connected to the  PWR plane. In a six-layer stacking with signal1-GND-signal2-PWR-GND-signal3, the lines on the top and bottom layer can both use the GND plane as a reference. If the lines change from the top to the bottom, we can connect the upper GND and lower GND planes to provide an integral return path for the electromagnetic wave.*

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Expecting to learn the layout of Type-C and DisplayPort.

Comment: A differential pair embodies its own current return path. A more helpful and less ambiguous image might help; it all looks noisy to me.

Comment: @Andyaka I have uploaded a clearer pdf version of the schematic.

Comment: How does the eye-diagram look?

Comment: @winny Hi, winny. I'm an amateur so I don't have an advanced instrument to measure the eye-diagram. If I manage to get that, I will upload it here.

Comment: Ouch! Do you know someone who have access to one? Impedance mismatches, decoupling issues and the like become very apparent in an eye-diagram.